# How to render icon and call function when click icon

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to do Lock/Unlock icon button by using Renderer. If clicking the button, it will show message box yes/no to confirm. If click Yes, it should call SubmitValue function. The problem is it cannot call javascript **SubmitValue** function. How do I call function when click Yes confirm box?

Renderer.js

```
var renderLock = function (value, p, record) {
    if (JSON.parse(value))
    {
        return '<img src="Images/icon/lock.png" >';
    }
    else 
    {
        return '<img src="Images/icon/unlock.png" >';
    }
}
```

Common.js

```
var GetGrid_LockButton = function (Active, FieldId, FieldName, Grid_Name, URL) {
return {
    menuDisabled: true
    , sortable: false
    , hidden: Permit_No_Del
    , text: 'Lock'
    , renderer: renderLock
    , align: 'center'
    , xtype: 'actioncolumn'
    , dataIndex: 'IS_LOCK'
    , width: 45
    , listeners: {
        click: function () {
            Ext.MessageBox.confirm('confirm?', function (btn) {
                if (btn == "yes") {      
                    SubmitValue(URL, { id: rec.get(FieldId) }, "Ext.getCmp('" + Grid_Name + "').getStore().load();", "Yes");
                }
            });

        }
    }
   };
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are possibly having problems with scope, notice the 'this' keyword added as the last param in the modified version of your confirm call below

```
Ext.MessageBox.confirm('confirm?', function (btn) {
    if (btn == "yes") {      
        SubmitValue(URL, { id: rec.get(FieldId) }, "Ext.getCmp('" + Grid_Name + "').getStore().load();", "Yes");
    }
},this);
```

By default, the scope in a confirm call is defaulted to the browser window object and so I imagine at that level your SubmitValue function is not accessible.